# SQL Server 2016: Adding temporal tables to existing application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I have a big PHP application, developed by an external company, which is being completed right now; I cannot ask for changes to it.
It uses a database Microsoft SQL Server 2016, which is accessed by some users via SSMS, including me, and by some scheduled tasks at specific times of day.
Sometimes I find unexpected content in some tables, and it is frustrating because I don't know when it got there.
I just discovered about temporal tables: knowing the exact date and time when a record changes would be extremely useful.

Is it possible to add temporal tables to 2-3 key tables in the application, without changing the PHP code? Are there risks of compatibility or performances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***Is it possible to add temporal tables to 2-3 key tables in the
>   application, without changing the PHP code?***

You should be able to achieve that goal (assuming the application is written in a way that adding additional columns to the table doesn't cause a problem).  Of course, *test, test, test*.

Using the example code provided in Greg Larsen's post 
[Altering an Existing Table to Support Temporal Data](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/altering-an-existing-table-to-support-temporal-data.html), let's work through an example.

Here is our current table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Product
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.ProductHistory

CREATE TABLE dbo.Product (
    ID INT Identity
    ,ProductName VARCHAR(50)
    ,ProductPrice DECIMAL(20, 2)
    );

INSERT INTO dbo.Product (ProductName, ProductPrice)
VALUES ('Widget',33.49),('Doo-Hickey',21.76),('Thing-A-Ma-Jig',20.16);

SELECT * FROM dbo.Product
```

---

```
| ID | ProductName    | ProductPrice |
|----|----------------|--------------|
| 1  | Widget         | 33.49        |
| 2  | Doo-Hickey     | 21.76        |
| 3  | Thing-A-Ma-Jig | 20.16        |
```

We now want to track *versions*.

> In order to start collecting historical information for my dbo.Product
>   table I will need to alter the table so it will support temporal data.
>   A SQL Server 2016 temporal table requires a table to have a primary
>   key and a couple for date/time columns.  The two date/time columns
>   will be used to determine the period of time for when the record is
>   valid.   Therefore the first thing I need to do is alter my Product
>   table to meet the temporal data table requirements.  To do that I will
>   run the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Product 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ProductID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    BeginDate datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
        DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME()
,
    EndDate datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL
        DEFAULT CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999' AS datetime2),
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (BeginDate,EndDate);
```

There is some very good information in [Creating a System-Versioned Temporal Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table) that addresses *Altering Non-Temporal Table to be System-Versioned Temporal Table*.

> When converting an existing table, consider using the **HIDDEN** clause to
>   hide the new **PERIOD** columns to avoid impacting existing applications
>   that are not designed to handle new columns.

---

> The next step in setting up a temporal table is to identify a history
>   table that goes along with my dbo.Product table.  To do that I will
>   run the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Product
        SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.ProductHistory));
```

Now the `Product` table looks like this

```
| ProductName    | ProductPrice | BeginDate                   | EndDate                     |
|----------------|--------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|
| Widget         | 33.49        | 2017-09-29 14:28:04.8327739 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| Doo-Hickey     | 21.76        | 2017-09-29 14:17:55.7149252 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| Thing-A-Ma-Jig | 20.16        | 2017-09-29 14:17:55.7149252 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
```

You also find that a new `ProductHistory` table has been created that looks just like the `Product` table.  The `ProductHistory` table is currently empty because we haven't updated or deleted anything from the Product table

Now, let's run an update to generate some history

```
UPDATE dbo.Product 
SET ProductPrice = 34.65
WHERE ProductName = 'Widget';

select * from dbo.Product
select * from dbo.Producthistory
```

The `product` table has the *current* data

```
| ProductName    | ProductPrice | BeginDate                   | EndDate                     |
|----------------|--------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|
| Widget         | 34.65        | 2017-09-29 14:35:49.7943164 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| Doo-Hickey     | 21.76        | 2017-09-29 14:35:41.8079586 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| Thing-A-Ma-Jig | 20.16        | 2017-09-29 14:35:41.8079586 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
```

And now the `ProductHistory` table has a versioned row

```
| ProductName | ProductPrice | BeginDate                   | EndDate                     |
|-------------|--------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|
| Widget      | 33.49        | 2017-09-29 14:35:41.8079586 | 2017-09-29 14:35:49.7943164 |
```

You can even add a column to the `Product` table and the `ProductHistory` table automatically gets the new column added as well

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Product ADD ProductColor VARCHAR(10)
```

`Product`

```
| ProductName    | ProductPrice | BeginDate                   | EndDate                     | ProductColor |
|----------------|--------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|--------------|
| Widget         | 34.65        | 2017-09-29 14:35:49.7943164 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 | NULL         |
| Doo-Hickey     | 21.76        | 2017-09-29 14:35:41.8079586 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 | NULL         |
| Thing-A-Ma-Jig | 20.16        | 2017-09-29 14:35:41.8079586 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 | NULL         |
```

`ProductHistory`

```
| ProductName | ProductPrice | BeginDate                   | EndDate                     | ProductColor |
|-------------|--------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|--------------|
| Widget      | 33.49        | 2017-09-29 14:35:41.8079586 | 2017-09-29 14:35:49.7943164 | NULL         |
```

---

> ***Are there risks of compatibility or performances?***

You would certainly need to test this in a development environment first.  You may have unique situations that have an impact on your decision to use Temporal tables.

Here are a few important links with additional information regarding  Temporal tables

[Getting Started with System-Versioned Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/getting-started-with-system-versioned-temporal-tables)

[Temporal Table Considerations and Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-considerations-and-limitations)

[Manage Retention of Historical Data in System-Versioned Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/manage-retention-of-historical-data-in-system-versioned-temporal-tables)

[Stopping System-Versioning on a System-Versioned Temporal Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/stopping-system-versioning-on-a-system-versioned-temporal-table)